# Cinnamon task bar showing, but not working (i.e. not clickable)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, cinnamon, taskbar

Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Respectively I upgraded the Cinnamon version to 3.0. So I have the following installed:

**Ubuntu:** 16.04 
**Cinnamon:** 3.0.7

My issue is as mentioned in the title. My task bar works perfectly, it's there, it shows all of the windows, status updates from messengers, system information (sound, network, time, etc.)... But it's not clickable. I can't select a window, can't open the menu, can't open the clock. It doesn't even highlight any of the windows if I hover over them.

I have never ran into such an issue and it's quite the mystery to me, so if you have **any** ideas, please go ahead.

**P.S.** I tried reinstalling cinnamon, didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling some graphical packages (don't recall which exactly) and the **Nvidia drivers** seems to have solved the issue.